# Partial Fractions and Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I have $\int_{C}\frac{e^z}{z^2 + a^2}$ where $a>0$ and $C$ is a positively oriented simple closed contour containing the circle $|z|=1$.

I start with 
$$\frac{1}{z^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{(z+ia)(z-ia)} = \frac{A}{z+ia} + \frac{B}{z-ia}$$
Then,$$1 = z(A + B) + ia(-A + B)$$ Shouldn't we then have $$A+B =0, \; -A+B = 1$$? This turns out to be incorrect and I want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you get:

$A+B = 0$ and $ia(-A+B) = 1$. (You can't just drop the $ia$ factor.)